# What is the right word for "eliminating" a law?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say there is a Law in my country and I think it should be "abolished", what is the proper word to use for asking that ? I tough of : eliminate, get rid off, eradicate, erase, abolish, terminate. But I don't know which word is the correct "law" vocabulary to use.

**Example** : "The Law of Gravity should be abolished because it never was voted inside Canadian Parliament."

I'm trying to write an official letter in English, and yes, I am a French Canadian :)

Thanks for your help,

-Séb

Comment: Laws are rescinded or abolished. It was never voted ON in the Canadian Parliament.

Comment: _Abolish_ is likely the best choice here, because, as you say, the law of gravity was never passed by parliamentary vote. Both _rescind_, _revoke_, and _repeal_ are used to describe getting rid of a law, but they all imply that the law is actually written into the books, which the law of gravity isn’t. _Abolish_ is broader and can be used for any kind of system that’s gotten rid of.

Comment: I don't know if you're trying to be humorous, but natural laws are discovered (and perhaps what were formerly thought to be laws may be disproved); they are neither passed nor repealed.

Comment: Yes of course this is humour ! But it can be serious humour. It has to be made appropriatly.

Comment: A mix of irony, exaggeration, and some elliptical phrasing? Not a native speaker but consider the total rephrase: _Just like the Law of Gravity doesn't exist because it was never made into an act of Parliament._ Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Repeal

[Uk legislation is marked as repealed on the government website](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/1970?title=Equal%20Pay%20Act)

"The Law of Gravity should be repealed because it never was voted inside Canadian Parliament."

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Is it because it gives a UK answer? The answer is certainly accurate - UK laws (Acts specifically) *are* repealed. Very occasionally an Act will be rescinded (which means removed as if it had never had effect, as opposed to repealed, which means they no longer have effect).

Comment: Yep, the same term is used in the US.

Comment: You do get "drive-by shooters" on the site who downvote without leaving any explanation. It says more about them than it does about you, Ned. It is only with the most outrageous or offensive answers that I will use a downvote. Anyway +1 for a good answer.

Comment: [This](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/I-21/page-5.html#h-32) should confirm your answer can apply to Canada. Another bit you may be aware of is that you can use ["in the House"](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=HOUSE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) to mean the _in the Parliament of Canada_ in context with a British type of parliamentary system, if the syntax allows for it; in any case _House_ with the initial uppercase is certainly useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**abrogate**

abolish or eliminate a law by official action.

https://books.google.com/books?id=RWT8CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT20&ots=toz6FPd89G&dq=%22eliminating%20a%20law%22%20phrases&pg=PT20#v=onepage&q=%22eliminating%20a%20law%22%20phrases&f=false